# админка сайта: объединение 2-х моделей в единое древо с использованием feincms

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

имеются 2 модели:

models.py

```
import mptt
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Catalog(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='%(class)s_children')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,help_text="Optional")

class Product(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, blank=True, verbose_name='Папка', related_name='+')
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default='product_slug', max_length=60,    null=True, blank=True)
```

для отображения в админке использую feincms

admin.py

```
from feincms.admin import tree_editor

class CatalogAdmin(tree_editor.TreeEditor):
    tree_auto_open = True

admin.site.register(Catalog, CatalogAdmin)
```

Собственно вопрос: как объединить 2 модели для отображения в админке сайта в виде древа?
Данным кодом отображается только древо каталогов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вам действительно нужен монстр feincms, или вам просто нужно вывести дерево с драг&дропом категорий и товаров в админке? Если только дерево, то есть лёгкое приложение, которое реализует исключительно этот функционал: https://github.com/kjefes/django-treeadmin

По сути вопроса, встречал вот такую реализацию, надеюсь подойдёт: http://djbook.ru/forum/topic/1896/#post-12991

Да и немного режет глаз название модели Catalog, это несколько неточно, модель в django orm представляет таблицу, а экземпляр модели - строку, судя по контексту вам больше подошло бы название Category или Section - что-нибудь в этом роде. А Catalog - это скорее общее название приложения, которое вы разрабатываете.